# Intermediate commit along with Rollback

Tags: sql, c

I have save point issued to commit 300 records in C . However once a fatal comes(divide by 0) i would want to rollback the records processsed , as well as update one table for recording this fatal record. How can i do commit for this fatal table alone and rollback previous records.

Comment: Why all close-votes? I think this is a fair question. (Some more info could however be needed.)

Comment: Do the logging in a separate transaction. You haven't listed which DBMS you use, but in Oracle you can use `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` to mark that a procedure should always use a separate transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL server :

Use TRY - CATCH method : If fatal error occurred then it goes to catch block and rollback transactions and after that rollback update fatal record into one table.If fatal error not occurred transactions committed as usual.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure_Name
 (
  @Parameter1 Data_type, 
  @Parameter2 Data_type
 ) 
 AS
 BEGIN TRY

    --- your SQL statements
    COMMIT TRAN

 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN

    --After rollback fatal record SQL statements      
      INSERT (or) UPDATE your fatal record
 END CATCH
```